# Exception Handling in Spring Boot + Schedulers + Spring Data JPA + Oracle

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to figure out what all the exception's can be handled/caught and process for some other means like DB insert into a table?

Majorly, there is no controller or API is being exposed. Instead only schedulers read the data from Oracle DB table by JPA Queries (i.e., Not Native Queries) and used Pessimistic WRITE Locking with Query hints as timeout specified. Later, processed data will be sent to external system as byte array.

I encountered few exceptions like JPASystemException, LocktimeoutException and others but somehow, I couldn't catch them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use AOP and define pointcuts and advices for all methods that access the db and might throw an exception. Spring offers advices such as AfterThrowing and Around which can hold your error handling logic.

Comment: Any reference or snippets please?

Comment: There are wast amounts of examples online. For example: [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springaop/springaop_around_aspect1.htm)

Comment: Seems good. Thanks But I'm thinking to achieve in a simple, standard exception handling types & store it in DB table for auditing/logging purpose. AOP will completely change my design.